# Probability of collision in a prime number hash space?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I'm trying to figure out that, if given a hash space of size *m* that is represented by a prime number, what is the probability that two distinct strings hash to the same value (i.e. a collision occurs)?

The hash function can be represented by the following equation:

[image: The hashing function]

Where *c* represents each character in a given string and *a* is an arbitrary integer. Is there any good way to determine the probability of a collision from this?

Comment: What's the probability distribution for the input strings to the hash? Without that distribution, there's no way to calculate the collision probability.

Comment: I'm not familiar... hashing is new to me and I've been thrown in the deep end. What I've given is essentially all I have available to me to solve which is why I'm so confused. Here's the context, see 5.1.3 for the current question but the previous two for other info: [context](https://i.imgur.com/DVy5lDL.png)

Comment: You haven't accurately reproduced the question, which is the probability of two distinct string's hashes colliding if `a` is chosen randomly, and that there's 2 hints about polynomials mod m (prime) being a field and the maximum number of roots of polys.

Comment: The random choice of `a` is important, because it means that even if you choose evil strings, it's hard to get them to collide for many values of `a`. I guess the answer is something like that the probability is less than `max(len(s1), len(s2))/m`

Comment: hint: write out the equation for the hashes of two strings being equal, and then see how many values of a (from 0 to m-1) satisfy the equation.